Calculate the average wait in days with a condition based on another column
I'm trying to calculate the average wait for a location in days. I have managed to calculate the average wait for a person in days using
=DATEDIF('Jun24'!V8,'Jun 24'!AA8,"d")
This gives me the average wait in days. However, I have a column for location, with the options The Vale or ESD. I want to calculate the average wait in days on the condition of it being one or the other.


Is what I'm trying to do possible with only these columns?
Thanks

You need AVERAGEIFS() function. Read_Here

Like this: =AVERAGEIFS('May 24'!V8,'May 24'!AA8,"d",'May 24'!U8:U207,"The Vale")
I have tried this and it comes up with a #VALUE! error

No it will not work that way. It is is wrong syntax. Click on the link read here to read the Microsoft documentation or post some sample data. Btw the formula will be =AVERAGEIFS('May 24'!V8:V207,'May 24'!AA8:AA207,"d",'May 24'!U8:U207,"The Value") where it needs to have a column with 'd' as well as range of values and range for "The Value"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I've added images of the spreadsheets I'm working with.

Consider converting your summary page to a table with CTRL  + t and adding a Totals row. In the totals row, select AVERAGE in your days column. When you filter for one of the options the totals row (average) will apply only to the visible rows.
